# Android: Proxy or VPN server?

Tags: android, vpn, proxy

It is easy for Android to be a client for a proxy or client for a VPN server. But I want to do the opposite: I want the Android phone to be the server so I can connect to that from another phone and access the internet through the first phone.

Does such a beast exist? Does it work if the server is behind NAT?

Comment: If it's just about using the other devices internet connection, you don't need specific VPN features, and both devices are close to each other, my first thought would be using the on-board hotspot feature. Through a firewall (NAT) things might become tricky in any case; I don't know about a VPN server solution.

Comment: It is possible to run a server in Android by using the nanohttpd server. It is a small embeddable server and it can easily be integrated into Android code. However, I am not aware of any already existing application that provide this behaviour. You will have to code it yourself